# DataGridView showing extra digits after importing excel sheet in windows application

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

Excel cell contain only $248.40 and it is set as currency format. But it is showing 284.3899 in DataGridView.

Can you please help how can i show as it is what ever excel sheet contain in DataGridView.

Comment: What is the datatype used ? you could use a format like `0.00` or say `N2`

Answer (score 2):

Go to DataGridView `Columns` property. Select the `Column(Cell)` which you want to format. And in `Appearances` section, browse the button of `DefaultCellStyle`. A dialog form will be open. Here you can set the Format of your cell in the `Format` Property.

Set here the decimal format property `'#.##'`. This will set the property at Design time. If you want to set the property at runtime than see the answer of Vok.

More on numeric Formatting, Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: In Excel sheet i saw in address bar that specific cell value.it is not showing 4 digits.I need to figure out not setting format of datagirdview.I hope some thing wrong on excel sheet format.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying value in the spreadsheet probably contains more digits.

You need to apply formatting to your datagridview

```
DataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.##"
```

Comment: Thanks your reply ! I need to show how many digits in excel sheet. Not exactly two digits.